# Set Min-Height of Background Color to Fit Page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple webpage with the center content with a red background. I'd like that background color to reach all the way to the bottom of the page, regardless of whether there is that much content in it or not.

I've tried various combinations of methods but nothing seems to stretch it correctly. In the Fiddle, I am attempting to use a flexbox but it doesn't appear to be working.

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

.main {
  max-width: 80%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-content: stretch;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<section class="main">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce at aliquam dolor. Pellentesque a nibh in magna blandit elementum. Sed sodales porttitor dolor vel bibendum. Ut viverra justo in elit scelerisque, nec accumsan arcu facilisis. Nam ultricies
    leo vitae felis sollicitudin lobortis. Cras nec nibh venenatis, bibendum neque at, suscipit lacus. Vestibulum interdum sodales cursus. Pellentesque feugiat eu velit venenatis egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam
    faucibus risus quis est pellentesque ultrices.
  </p>
</section>
```

```
<section class="main">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
</section>

body
{
    background-color:white;
}

.main
{
    max-width:80%;
    background-color:red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;

    display:flex;
    align-content:stretch;
    flex-direction:row;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I've tried various combinations of methods but nothing seems to stretch it correctly*

I assume that you don't want a `flex` ONLY solution, because you can actually achieve this without the flex, so if that's the point, than set the parent elements `height` to `100%`

**Demo**

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  max-width: 80%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="main">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce at aliquam dolor. Pellentesque a nibh in magna blandit elementum. Sed sodales porttitor dolor vel bibendum. Ut viverra justo in elit scelerisque, nec accumsan arcu facilisis. Nam ultricies
    leo vitae felis sollicitudin lobortis. Cras nec nibh venenatis, bibendum neque at, suscipit lacus. Vestibulum interdum sodales cursus. Pellentesque feugiat eu velit venenatis egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam
    faucibus risus quis est pellentesque ultrices.
  </p>
</section>
```

Also, you would see, am using the snippet below

```
* {
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

will do nothing but count the `borders`, `padding` of the element inside instead of default box model which counts these outside the element, thus it won't result in vertical scroll as you were using `padding` and I used `height: 100%;` so as I explained, `padding` will be counted outside of the element, and will thus result in scroll.

Comment: I prefer a flexbox implementation as I find that they are generally cleaner once implemented, but I am open to any solution. Yours appears to work marvelously.

Comment: @Dragonseer Flexbox is not widely supported yet, am a CSS fan but I still don't go for the flexbox, as it will result in nothing but ending up using cross browser compatibility polyfills/scripts

Comment: There does appear to be a small problem with your solution. If the page contains more text than what can fit on the screen, then the background stops abruptly halfway down. See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dragonseer/2FLK2/). Also, my site only targets browsers that support the Flexbox Candidate Recommendation, so compatibility isn't a huge issue.

Comment: @Dragonseer than use `min-height: 100%;` for `.main` add the content here and see http://jsfiddle.net/2FLK2/2/

Answer (score 2):

`box-sizing` is a good option, its a CSS3 property.

I have one more option.

```css
body, html {
    min-height:100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
}
.innerBox {
    min-height:100%;
    width: 80%;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="innerBox">
    Testing
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a new div for wrapping your content ?
Like this http://jsfiddle.net/MNQjk/2/

```
.block
{
  max-width:80%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I want my background to go as far as the bottom of the page, but no further. That is, I don't want to generate a scroll bar if I can avoid it.